# How can I play the song which is in the raw folder with the use of path gotten from database as a string?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-mediaplayer

I have stored a .mp3 file on raw folder in my Android studio and I have received the path of that file as a string, now How can I play the song with the use of that string using media player?

I have tried enter the string name like the code below

```
 a = cursor.getString(2);

Context context = this;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.a);
mediaPlayer.start();
```

how can I insert that string inside the MediaPlayer.create()  method?

Comment: What is the format of the string?

Comment: it's in String  format